# Using existing reports as subreports in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I created 5 separate reports using Pentaho Report Designer, but I now need them in a single report. It seems like I should be able to merge them into one report via subreports, but I've been unable to do so.

The tutorial I found online seems to suggest that I need to recreate each subreport individually, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient process for this?

Answer (score 0):

No It's impossible to merge those reports using subreports since sub report is a part of main report. Sub report and main report are in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but for new users that have found your question, here is a way to achieve what you describe: http://wiki.bizcubed.com.au/xwiki/bin/view/Pentaho+Tutorial/Subreports

Now that Pentaho Community Edition version 5 was released a lot ot things are new, better and more powerful than earlier versions.

I hope this will be useful for more than one.